# OAuth React Native

Tags: android, react-native, oauth, oauth-2.0, github-api

I was looking into using react native to make android applications and and into using APIs. I learned sending basic API calls to GitHub API. However to send put calls I need to authenticate my GitHub account. I don't know how to do this. How do I have a simple username/password authentication or simply pass in the Client ID and Client Secret?

Comment: No, you do need to go through the OAuth process: you can't just use the secret. There are libraries you can use to do this for you, e.g. https://github.com/fullstackreact/react-native-oauth (first hit on searching, haven't tried it myself)

Comment: @Rup Can i not do something like: handlefollow(){
 fetch('https://api.github.com/user/following/muan', { 
   method: 'PUT', 
   headers: new Headers({
     'Authorization': 'Basic ' + base64.encode('username:password'), 
   }), 
 });
}  I saw someone else using it for a different API but I cant seem to make it work. What am I doing wrong here?